# Can't set property value

Tags: html, angular

I'm trying to set initial value of input field using:

```
<input type="text" id="inputText2" name="inputText2" ngModel #inputText2="ngModel" size="5" autocomplete="off" [value]="'hre'"
autofocus>
```

Tried everything [value]="example", [ngValue] - here I've got that isn't know property of input field. Thanks for help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just let the `ngModel` handle setting the value for you.

component.html

```
<input [(ngModel)]="value" />
```

component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  value = 'hello';
}
```

[Live demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-phsnfo)

Comment: I have also question about checkboxes. How I can in template driven form set checkbox to be checked? <input type="checkbox" name="testCheckbox" ngModel>Test1

Comment: Can you accept my answer here, and create a separate question for the checkbox? It's best to keep the questions focused on a single problem.

Comment: Answer is accepted, but I can't make a new post because of 90 minutes limit :/

Comment: Thanks, have a nice day ;)

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest:

HTML:

```
<input [(ngModel)]="yourModel" ... />
```

TS:

```
...
public class YourComponent{
    yourModel: string = '';

...
}
```

But you can read on other solutions from the [official guide here](https://angular.io/guide/user-input).

Comment: Your answer is a direct copy of my answer, which I posted earlier.

Comment: @TomaszKula, I believe we posted them at the same time.